# git push -u origin –all error: src refspec –all does not match an

Tags: git, gitlab, devops

I am trying to do svn to git migration so followed option 2 of [the guide](https://josh-ops.com/posts/migrate-svn-to-git/).

AFter fixing issues after issues, now I am step 7. I see the below error when i run step 7

```
git push -u origin -–all
error: src refspec –-all does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:<dir>/my.git'
```

then I saw on stackoverflow to run

```
git remote -v
```

and it turned out to be the correct one as below

```
origin  git@gitlab.com:<dir>/my.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:<dir>/my.git (push)
```

then per the answer on stackoverflow i ran

```
git fetch origin main
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref main
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: ERROR: user canceled the fetch

remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
```

I couldnt get any answer on stackflow or google search. Hence checking here to see if the experts can chime in.

The migration has been a pain :) svn2git too many issues, reposurgeon not straightforward and hit hiccups after hiccups :(

Comment: Try `git push origin --all` instead of `git push -u origin --all`

Comment: In `git push -u origin -–all` please compare `-` vs `–` vs `—`. These are different kinds (dash/minus, n-dash, m-dash), in command line use ascii minuses (dashes and double-dashes): `git push -u origin --all`

Comment: I tried --all itself but i still see the problem. I tried with -u and without -u but have same problem.    git push origin –-all
error: src refspec –-all does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:<dir>/my.git'

Comment: `git push origin –-all` <- the same mistake again: wrong 1st dash. Must be `git push origin --all`